# Galaxy S3 (Jellybean 4.1.2) is blocking callers on Allowed list while in Blocking Mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, call-screening

I discovered last night that my phone is blocking callers who are on my approved list. I couldn't find my phone and asked my husband to call it... but it went straight to voicemail. When I finally found my phone it showed a missed call from my husband, with an indication that the call was [blocked].

I fiddled with the Blocking Mode settings - I switched from Custom List to Favorites to All Contacts - but his calls only came through when Blocking Mode was off. What could be the cause for the erroneous blocking? Am I just S.O.L. here or is there a fix?

Comment: Does it allow notifications for text messages from allowed persons come through or do they get blocked also?